# TableView in navigation stack does not animate back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uikit

I've got `UINavigationController` with `UITableViewController` as root controller. When I push another controller over it (for detail view of row), the new controller appear with animation from right. But when I hit the back button on `UINavigationBar`, it just animates the navigation bar (labels, buttons) but the `UITableView` appear instantly without animation. Does anybody have a clue what am I doing wrong?

Cells of that table have little bit changed views, but nothing big.

This is how it looks like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Bww333BsJo

Thx

Comment: @beny First provide your code which you have written.

Comment: @benny One thing i like to suggest you.Try to Use UIviewController instead of UItableViewController and add UItableView on that UIviewController.
Now,I think your code may be work properly.

Comment: Don't want do that, that's not a solution. And about the code, there is a lot of code, cannot post it all here, what patrs are you interested in?

Comment: Probably "there is a lot of code" is the problem. I imagine that if you built a new, simple, project containing just the two VCs that this wouldn't be a problem. I think somewhere in there the animation is getting set to NO. I would start looking for that.

Comment: thx @psoft, I was away from computer for fresh air and then read your comment and problem solved, there was overriden viewWillAppear method and the animation boolean was not send to super. thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had overriden method `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` and forgot to send animated boolen to super. Thx to @psoft for help.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to Used UIViewController...instead of UITableViewController And Add the Object UITableView .. IT's work Perfectly...Or let me know what you code there i Surely help you..

Comment: Is there any real reason for that? UITableViewController is a descendat of UIViewController suited to display a UITableView...

Comment: That's right, what is _wrong_ with `UITableViewController`? I want to know the reason why is my solution wrong to avoid it in a future.

Answer (score 0):

Overrride the back button in navigation bar, so it responds for example to the method '-(void)back:(id)sender', this method should look like this:

```
- (void)back:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

if you pass NO, it will pop without any animation

Comment: nothing changed, tried to pop it myself but the problem is still there

Comment: The I would like to see some code.
My guess is the TableViewController. Always use UIViewController as rootViewController, add a uitableview as subview and make the viewcontroller the 2 delegates.